# bootstrap table, sorting columns with custom sorter based on row attribute

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I'm using the "Bootstrap Table" API : https://bootstrap-table.com/.
The problem i'm having is that I have my field set up with the attributes :

```
{field: 'price', title: 'prices', sortable: true, sorter: "customSorter"}
```

By extension, my custom sorter look like this :

```
function customSorter(fieldA, fieldB) {

}
```

What I would like is being able to access my row attributes inside the customSorter function, because I'd like some of my row that have a specific attribute (for instance if row.important is set to true) to appear on top of the list no matter what. I've seen that you can access those with "Bootstrap datatable" because custom sorter are like this :

```
function customSorter(fieldA, fieldB, rowA, rowB) {

}
```

But I don't want to change for that since the code is huge allready, is there a trick that I don't know of that could do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a attribute easy with `rowA.<attribute>` e.g. `rowA.important`.
The problem is if you check for that attribute and retun 1 on the sorter it only works for desc ordering.
The reason is that the bootstrap-table internal negate the result of the formatter to sort is asc.

Currently there is no additional parameter to check if the user sorts asc or desc.
Please open a issue on the bootstrap-table repository and it will be added soon.